# Tree string to bracketed string

Tags: python, tree, nltk

Let's say I have a tree string for a sentence:

```
s = "(TOP (S (NP-TMP (NP (DT This) (NN time)) (ADVP (RP around))) (NP-SBJ (PRP they)) (VP (VBP 're) (VP (VBG moving) (ADVP (RB even) (RBR faster))))))"
```

[image]

I want to convert it into a bracketed structure like this:

```
"(((This time)(around))(they)(('re)((moving)(even faster))))"
```

I tried to do the following:

```
import nltk

s = "(TOP (S (NP-TMP (NP (DT This) (NN time)) (ADVP (RP around))) (NP-SBJ (PRP they)) (VP (VBP 're) (VP (VBG moving) (ADVP (RB even) (RBR faster))))))"
tree = nltk.Tree.fromstring(s)

out = "("
for subtrees in tree:
    # there are threee subtrees
    # print(len(subtree))
    for i, subtree in enumerate(subtrees):
        if len(subtree) > 1:
            out += "("
        for bracketing in range(len(subtree)):
            # print(subtree[bracketing])
            flattened_tree = subtree[bracketing].flatten()
            flattened_string = str(flattened_tree)
            flattened_string = flattened_string.replace(flattened_tree.label() + " ", "")
            print(flattened_string)
            out += flattened_string
        if len(subtree) > 1:
            out += ")"
        # break
out += ")"

print(out)
# (((This time)(around))(they)(('re)(moving even faster)))
```

**Edit:**

if you see, `"This"` and `"time"` are part of the same parent, `"NP"`. So, they become contiguous constituents, i.e. `(This time)`.

Whereas, `"around"` is a single word constituent although a part of the same left sub-tree. So, it becomes `((This time)(around))`.

Similarly, for the case of the right-subtree - `"'re"` and `"'moving even faster"`, we see that `"moving"` as well as `"even faster"` share the same parent, `"VP"`.

So, it becomes, `(('re)((moving)(even faster))`.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Your posted code is not minimal; your problem seems unrelated to NLTK; some of your code exists only to convert the missing input from NLTK to string, and you have at least one undefined symbol.  You neglected to provide your diagnostic trace -- where is your code removing desired parentheses (you have no brackets in this)?  For starters, this seems to be a straightforward case for a simple recursive routine, rather than a loop.  Clean this up, so we can help trace and diagnose.

Comment: I have provided a complete working example. Did you even try running the script? I am replacing certain labels with an empty string by converting the tree structure to a raw string. Hope it's much clearer now.

Comment: Got it; your example was not contiguous.  You still haven't tried tracing the intermediate results, but this is short enough that perhaps someone will do that part of the work for you.

Comment: Updated with more details and a better attempt to reproduce what I desire.

Comment: You still suffer from stopping early to squash the phrase flat, ignoring further depth.

Comment: Yes, I am struggling to break this string "(moving even faster)" into it's constituents. Do you know of a solution?

Comment: Can you explain the logic for when brackets should be added and when not? I don't entirely get it.

Comment: For eg, if you see, "This" and "time" are part of the same parent, "NP". So, they become contiguous constituents, i.e. (This time). Whereas, "around" is a single word constituent although a part of the same left sub-tree. So, it becomes ((This time)(around)). Similarly, for the case of the right-subtree - "'re" and "'moving even faster", we see that "moving" as well as "even faster" share the same parent, "VP". So, it becomes, (('re)((moving)(even faster)). I hope this explanation is clear.

Comment: Why does "moving" need its own brackets, and "even" not?

Comment: From what I understand, "moving", "even", "faster" is part of the same parent "VP". So, I think it becomes ((moving)(even faster)) cause they are now treated as a single unit. So, there is a common outer bracket between these words. @nikinlpds: Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely correct :)

Comment: That part I understand (why they get all in a bracket pair). Don't see the description for why `moving` needs its own pair of brackets in there, and it can't be `(moving (even faster))`. I posted my answer making an assumption about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to add brackets to an atomic string when it has a sibling that is not an atomic string, but already a bracketed combination, so that you would never have a pattern like this:

```
(moving (even faster))
```

Or in other words, a space can only be a separator between two atomic strings.

I would do this in two recursive passes:

- A first one to convert the tree to a nested list. This will make it easier to make distinctions for the above mentioned rule.
- A second pass to convert that nested list to the final bracketed string.

Code:

```
import nltk

def tolist(tree):
    if isinstance(tree[0], str):
        return tree[0]
    res = [tolist(subtree) for subtree in tree]
    leaves = sum(isinstance(child, str) for child in res)
    if 0 < leaves < len(res): # if there is a mix of leaves and subtrees....
        # ...then wrap every leaf in a list
        return [[child] if isinstance(child, str) else child for child in res]
    return res

def tostr(lst):
    if isinstance(lst[0], str):  # assume all list members are strings
        return "(" + " ".join(lst) + ")"
    return "(" + "".join([tostr(sub) for sub in lst]) + ")"

# run on sample data
s = "(TOP (S (NP-TMP (NP (DT This) (NN time)) (ADVP (RP around))) (NP-SBJ (PRP they)) (VP (VBP 're) (VP (VBG moving) (ADVP (RB even) (RBR faster))))))"
tree = nltk.Tree.fromstring(s)
res = tostr(tolist(tree[0]))
print(res)
```